# Spring Cloud Stream - KafkaStreams - KafkaHeaderMapper

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

For the management of the headers of the messages that are produced/consumed in the Kafka binder there is the `KafkaHeaderMapper` interface, whose implementation as a bean can be configured with the following property: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName`.

Is there something similar for the **KafkaStreams** binder in Spring Cloud Stream? My intention is to be able to control how to deserialize/serialize or include/exclude message headers on stream input and output. does anyone know how to realize this?

Answer (score 2):

There is not an equivalent; for streams; Spring is only involved with setting up the infrastructure/topology; it is not involved with the runtime record processing.

You can, however, use a custom serializer/deserializer and manipulate the headers there.

Comment: As far as I can see, by creating a custom Serde for the in-x and out-x bindings, you can only manipulate the key and value of the message, but not the headers... is that so?
And if I also need to set the binding with useNativeEncoding/useNativeDecoding to false, I wouldn't even use the custom Serde.
As Spring is involved in the manipulation topology, would it be possible to configure the topology to add a step in the sources and sinks of the stream to do this job, that is, manipulate the headers to deserialize them in the input and serialize them in the last step of the Stream?

Comment: You can manipulate the headers in the serializer/deserializer (the methods that don't take a `Headers` parameter are no longer called). The Spring JSON (de)serializers add and remove headers this way. Yes, another option is to add transformers to the topology (near the beginning and the end) within your listener definition; the framework can't help with that.